# How to build query with multi level relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, relationship

I have three models. `Sponsor`, `Optin` and `Participant`. `Sponsor` has a one-to-many relationship with `Optin` and `Optin` has a one-to-one `Participant`.

Which make the models look like this:

Sponsor model

```
class Sponsor extends Model
{ 
    public function optins()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Optin::class);
    }
}
```

Optin model

```
class Optin extends Model
{    

    public function sponsor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sponsor::class);
    }
    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
    }
}
```

Participant model

```
class Participant extends Model
{
    public function optins()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Optin::class);
    }

    public function scopeCreatedToday($query)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today());
    } 
}
```

Now in a daily scheduled task I want to iterate through all participants that where created today and that opted in to a certain Sponsor to send them like an email or something. Now I got as far as echoing the id's of the belonging participants. But the next step is to get the participant object and filter them by the right created date. But I am a little lost on how to handle this.

```
$sponsor = Sponsor::find(1);
$count = $sponsor->optins()->count();
echo("Count: " . $count . "\n");
$optins = $sponsor->optins()->get();
foreach($optins as $optin)
{
    echo($optin->participant_id . "\n");
}
```

**EDIT:**
After rethinking the structure I figured out that `Optin` has a many-to-one relation with `Participant`.

Comment: Does your `optins` table have `sponsor_id` and `participant_id` columns?

Comment: Yes. I already use the relationships in other situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Participant` has a one-to-many relation with `Optin` I added the following relation on the `Sponsor` model. With the passing the `Optin` model als a second parameter to the `belongsToMany` method, since it functions as an intermediate table.

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class, Optin::class);
}
```

From there out I could easily get all the participants with adding subqueries belonging to the sponsor like so:

```
$sponsor = Sponsor::find(1); 
$participants = $sponsor->participants()->createdToday()->get();
foreach($participants as $participant)
{
    //do something with $participant
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want multi level data from same table this solution help you with hasmany relationship in laravel.and with('point') is function name.your name will be diferent.

```
class Master extends Model
{
    public function point() {
        return $this->hasMany(Master::class,'point_id')->with('point');
    }
}
```